# String Index Out Of Bounds Exception When Initializing Spark Context

Tags: java, apache-spark

I've been working with Spark for more than 5 years. Recently, I encountered a basic error I have never seen before, and it has stopped development cold. When I do a routine call to create a Spark Context, I get an ExceptionInInitializerError caused by a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. Here is a simple sample of my code:

```
public class SparkTest {
    public static final SparkConf SPARK_CONFIGURATION = new SparkConf().setAppName("MOSDEX").setMaster("local[*]");
    public static final JavaSparkContext SPARK_CONTEXT= new JavaSparkContext(SPARK_CONFIGURATION);
    public static final SparkSession SPARK_SESSION= SparkSession.builder()
            .config(SPARK_CONFIGURATION)
            .getOrCreate();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        setupTest();        
    }

    public static void setupTest() {
        List<Integer> data = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
        JavaRDD<Integer> distData = SPARK_CONTEXT.parallelize(data);
        int sum= distData.reduce((a, b) -> a + b);
        System.out.println("Sum of " + data.toString() + " = " + sum);
        System.out.println();
    }//SetupTest

    public SparkTest() {
        super();
    }

}//class SparkTest
```

Here is the error message chain:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform (file:/C:/Users/Owner/.m2/repository/org/apache/spark/spark-unsafe_2.11/2.4.5/spark-unsafe_2.11-2.4.5.jar) to method java.nio.Bits.unaligned()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
20/04/05 13:55:21 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.4.5
20/04/05 13:55:22 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:79)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.parseStaticMapping(Groups.java:116)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService(Groups.java:293)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:283)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:260)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:789)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:774)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:647)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2422)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2422)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getCurrentUserName(Utils.scala:2422)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:293)
    at io.github.JeremyBloom.mosdex.SparkTest.<clinit>(SparkTest.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end 3, length 2
    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:3720)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1909)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:50)
    ... 16 more
```

I also get the same error when I use SparkContext instead of JavaSparkContext. I've done extensive search for this error and have not seen anyone else who has it, so I don't think it's a bug in Spark. I've used this code in other applications previously (with earlier versions of Spark) without a problem.

I'm using the latest version of Spark (2.4.5). Why isn't this working?

Comment: hi check my answer you might be facing issue with java version HADOOP-14586

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using spark 2.4.5 and jdk1.8.0_181 its working fine for me

```
package examples;



import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class SparkTest {
  public static final SparkConf SPARK_CONFIGURATION = new SparkConf().setAppName("MOSDEX").setMaster("local[*]");
  public static final JavaSparkContext SPARK_CONTEXT= new JavaSparkContext(SPARK_CONFIGURATION);
  public static final SparkSession SPARK_SESSION= SparkSession.builder()
    .config(SPARK_CONFIGURATION)
    .getOrCreate();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    setupTest();
  }

  public static void setupTest() {
    List<Integer> data = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    JavaRDD<Integer> distData = SPARK_CONTEXT.parallelize(data);
    int sum= distData.reduce((a, b) -> a + b);
    System.out.println("Sum of " + data.toString() + " = " + sum);
    System.out.println();
  }//SetupTest

  public SparkTest() {
    super();
  }

}//class SparkTest
```

Result :

```
[2020-04-05 18:14:42,184] INFO Running Spark version 2.4.5 (org.apache.spark.SparkContext:54)

...

[2020-04-05 18:14:44,060] WARN Using an existing SparkContext; some configuration may not take effect. (org.apache.spark.SparkContext:66)
Sum of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] = 15
```

#### AFAIK you are facing issue with java version as mentioned in this. [HADOOP-14586](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-14586) StringIndexOutOfBoundsException breaks org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell on 2.7.x with Java 9

Change the java version which is suitable with hadoop version.

See here

## Latest Release (Spark 2.4.5) - Apache Spark docs

[Spark runs on Java 8, Python 2.7+/3.4+ and R 3.1+. For the Scala API, Spark 2.4.5 uses Scala 2.12. You will need to use a compatible Scala version (2.12.x).](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/#downloading)

#### NOTE : As per comment, java 13 is not supported by Spark. You need to downgrade the java version to java 8

Comment: Can I upgrade Hadoop instead? Or not use Hadoop? I want to use Java 13 so I can use text blocks in my testing (my application works with complex JSON files, and using text blocks makes it much easier to write test cases).

Comment: you cant use java 13 at this time till java 8 its supported

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that if you use Hadoop > 2.8, you can use Java 13 (I'm now using Hadoop 2.8.5). This is tricky if you are using Spark 2.4.5 because on Maven, it comes prebuilt with Hadoop 2.6. You have to create a separate dependency for Hadoop 2.8.5 which overrides the prebuilt components. It took me quite a bit of experimenting to make that work. Plus, I'm working in Windows, so I also needed to link Hadoop with winutils, which is another complication. None of this is very well documented, so I had to read a lot of posts on Stackoverflow to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with below versions

1)Spark with version  2.12-2.4.4 
2)Hadoop with version 2.6.5 
3)JDK with version    java 16 in Spring STS

Solution : In Spring STS corrected the jdk version to jdk 1.8 and issue is resolved.